# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

---

### Полная ошибка

```
E:\bot>python bot.py
Ignoring exception in command duel:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\bot\bot.py", line 1201, in duel
    _balance = line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

Не работает именно часть кода, которая заносит данные в файл. Всё остальное работает без ошибок.

---

### Код:

````
@bot.command()
async def duel(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if user != None:
        if user != author:
            hp1 = 100
            hp2 = 100

            emb0 = discord.Embed(
            title='Сражение',
            description=f'''
            ```py
            {author}Вызвал на бой {user}...
            ```
            ''')

            msg = await ctx.send(embed=emb0)
            await sleep(2)
            txt = ''
            m = 1
            while m != 0:

                dmg = random.randint(5, 25)
                hp2 -= dmg
                prev_txt = txt
                txt = f'{prev_txt} \n{author} нанёс {dmg} урона {user}.'

                emb1 = discord.Embed(
                title='Сражение',
                description=f'''
                ```py
                {txt}.
                --------------------------------
                У {author}: {hp1} жизней.
                У {user}: {hp2} жизней.
                ```
                ''')

                prev_txt = txt
                txt = f'{prev_txt} \n{user} нанёс {dmg} урона {author}.'

                await msg.edit(embed=emb1)
                await sleep(0.25)

                prev_dmg = dmg
                dmg = random.randint(5, 27)
                hp1 -= dmg

                emb2 = discord.Embed(
                title='Сражение',
                description=f'''
                ```py
                {msg}
                --------------------------------
                У {author}: {hp1} жизней.
                У {user}: {hp2} жизней.
                ```
                ''')

                await sleep(0.25)
                await msg.edit(embed=emb2)

                prev_dmg = dmg
                winner = None

                if hp2 <= 1:
                    winner = author
                    emb3 = discord.Embed(
                    title='Сражение',
                    description=f'''
                    ПОБЕДИТЕЛЬ: {winner}
                    ''')
                    await msg.edit(embed=emb3)
                    m = 0


                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "a+")
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "r")
                    line = file.read().split("\n")
                    _fights = line[0]
                    _fights = int(_fights)  if _fights else 0
                    _balance = line[1]
                    _balance =  int(_balance) if _balance else 0
                    _wins = line[2]
                    _wins=  int(_wins) if _wins else 0
                    _loses = line[3]
                    _loses =  int(_loses) if _loses else 0
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "r")
                    list_of_lines = file.readlines()
                    fights = int(_fights) + 1
                    balance = int(_balance) + random.randint(5, 30)
                    wins = int(_wins) + 1
                    loses = int(_loses) + 0
                    list_of_lines[0] = f"{fights}\n"
                    list_of_lines[1] = f"{balance}\n"
                    list_of_lines[2] = f"{wins}\n"
                    list_of_lines[3] = f"{loses}\n"
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "w")
                    file.writelines(list_of_lines)
                    file.close()

                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "a+")
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "r")
                    line = file.read().split("\n")
                    _fights = line[0]
                    _fights = int(_fights)  if _fights else 0
                    _balance = line[1]
                    _balance =  int(_balance) if _balance else 0
                    _wins = line[2]
                    _wins=  int(_wins) if _wins else 0
                    _loses = line[3]
                    _loses =  int(_loses) if _loses else 0
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "r")
                    list_of_lines = file.readlines()
                    fights = int(_fights) + 1
                    balance = int(_balance) - random.randint(5, 15)
                    wins = int(_wins) + 0
                    loses = int(_loses) + 1
                    list_of_lines[0] = f"{fights}\n"
                    list_of_lines[1] = f"{balance}\n"
                    list_of_lines[2] = f"{wins}\n"
                    list_of_lines[3] = f"{loses}\n"
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "w")
                    file.writelines(list_of_lines)
                    file.close()


                elif hp1 <= 1:
                    winner = user
                    emb3 = discord.Embed(
                    title='Сражение',
                    description=f'''
                    ПОБЕДИТЕЛЬ: {winner}
                    ''')
                    await msg.edit(embed=emb3)
                    m = 0


                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "a+")
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "r")
                    line = file.read().split("\n")
                    _fights = line[0]
                    _fights = int(_fights)  if _fights else 0
                    _balance = line[1]
                    _balance =  int(_balance) if _balance else 0
                    _wins = line[2]
                    _wins=  int(_wins) if _wins else 0
                    _loses = line[3]
                    _loses =  int(_loses) if _loses else 0
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "r")
                    list_of_lines = file.readlines()
                    fights = int(_fights) + 1
                    balance = int(_balance) + random.randint(5, 30)
                    wins = int(_wins) + 1
                    loses = int(_loses) + 0
                    list_of_lines[0] = f"{fights}\n"
                    list_of_lines[1] = f"{balance}\n"
                    list_of_lines[2] = f"{wins}\n"
                    list_of_lines[3] = f"{loses}\n"
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{user.id}.json", "w")
                    file.writelines(list_of_lines)
                    file.close()

                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "a+")
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "r")
                    line = file.read().split("\n")
                    _fights = line[0]
                    _fights = int(_fights)  if _fights else 0
                    _balance = line[1]
                    _balance =  int(_balance) if _balance else 0
                    _wins = line[2]
                    _wins=  int(_wins) if _wins else 0
                    _loses = line[3]
                    _loses =  int(_loses) if _loses else 0
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "r")
                    list_of_lines = file.readlines()
                    fights = int(_fights) + 1
                    balance = int(_balance) - random.randint(5, 15)
                    wins = int(_wins) + 0
                    loses = int(_loses) + 1
                    list_of_lines[0] = f"{fights}\n"
                    list_of_lines[1] = f"{balance}\n"
                    list_of_lines[2] = f"{wins}\n"
                    list_of_lines[3] = f"{loses}\n"
                    file.close()
                    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "w")
                    file.writelines(list_of_lines)
                    file.close()


        else:
            await ctx.send('Вы не можете вызвать на дуэль самого себя')

    else:
        await ctx.send('Упомяните пользователя, которого вызываете на дуэль.')
````

---

P.S: Не минусуйте пожалуйста, я впервые работаю с файлами и многого не понимаю.

Comment: Если `line` это содержимое из файла, значит в файле всего одна строка и `line[1]` указывает в несуществующую строку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Всё решилось довольно просто:

---

Все строки

```
file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "a+")
file.close()
```

Нужно было заменить на это:

---

```
if not os.path.exists(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json"):
    file = open(f"E:\\bot\\duels_db\\stats-{author.id}.json", "a+")
    file.write('0 \n0 \n0 \n0')
else:
    pass
file.close()
```

(нужен импорт os.path)

---

То, на что я заменил исходные строки создают файл, если он отсутствует и вписывает нужные мне 4 строки.
P.S. Спасибо @andreymal за объяснение значения ошибки.